Influence of objects under antenna path
I'd like to implement a WiFi module with esp device. There's a chip antenna on border and I've found that under this antenna is not advised to have ground planes. Actually I don't have any planes but I've some small LEDs mounted on the other side right under the antenna.
Is this a complete wrong design that I might rethink or will I just have some signal degradation at long ranges?
I don't know how much it will influence quality of transmission.

It would be best not to have anything right under or around the antenna, as every piece of wire (trace) can take away from the signal or block it, however small its influence.
Almost any external antenna should improve your signal, especially if you need equal sensitivity in all directions perpendicular to the antenna, or you could use a directional antenna which would significantly increase your signal levels in a certain direction.
Additionally, the height of your antenna also influences the range of your signal, due to clearer line of sight (fewer obstacles in the path of the signal) and ground effect.

To make sure your chip antenna can work correctly,  please remove all metallic wires or components underneath antenna clearance space.
This is why each antenna needs a own clearance space to ensure each individual antenna will work efficiently.
If you can share image of your design, it will be helpful to evaluate the impact more accurate.

While your design may work fine for short-range communication, it is generally not recommended to have any components directly under the antenna. For best performance, I would suggest trying to move the LEDs elsewhere. However, if relocating them is impractical , it’s worth tesring the setup and evaluating signal performance to see if the degradation is within acceptable limits.
